# Returning array is faster than returning an element of the array

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I just conducted this very interesting experiment and the results came out quite surprising.

The purpose of the test was to determine the best way, performance-wise, to get an element of an array. The reason is that I have a configuration class which holds settings in an associative mufti-dimensional array and I was not quite sure I was getting these values the best way possible.

**Data** (it is not really needed for the question, but I just decided to include it so you see it is quite a reasonable amount of data to run tests with)

```
$data = array( 'system' => [
    'GUI' =>
    array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'password' => '',
    ),
    'Constants' => array(
        'URL_QUERYSTRING' => true,
        'ERRORS_TO_EXCEPTIONS' => true,
        'DEBUG_MODE' => true,
    ),
    'Benchmark' =>
    array(
        'enabled' => false,
    ),
    'Translations' =>
    array(
        'db_connection' => 'Default',
        'table_name' =>
        array(
            'languages' => 'languages',
            'translations' => 'translations',
        ),
    ),
    'Spam' =>
    array(
        'honeypot_names' =>
        array(
            0 => 'name1',
            1 => 'name2',
            2 => 'name3',
            3 => 'name4',
            4 => 'name5',
            5 => 'name6',
        ),
    ),
    'Response' =>
    array(
        'supported' =>
        array(
            0 => 'text/html',
            1 => 'application/json',
        ),
    ),]
);
```

**Methods**

```
function plain($file, $setting, $key, $sub){
    global $data;

    return $data[$file][$setting][$key][$sub];
}

function loop(...$args){
    global $data;

    $value = $data[array_shift($args)];
    foreach($args as $arg){
        $value = $value[$arg];
    }

    return $value;
}

function arr(){
    global $data;

    return $data;
}
```

**Parameters** (when calling the functions)

```
loop('system', 'Translations', 'table_name', 'languages');
plain('system', 'Translations', 'table_name', 'languages');
arr()['system']['Translations']['table_name']['languages'];
```

Leaving aside any other possible flaws and focusing on performance only, I ran 50 tests with 10000 loops. Each function has been called 500000 times in total. The results are in average seconds per 10000 loops:

> loop: 100% - 0.0381 sec. Returns: languages
>
> plain: 38% - 0.0146 sec. Returns: languages
>
> arr: 23% - 0.0088 sec. Returns: languages

I was expecting `loop` to be quite slow because there is logic inside, but looking at the results of the other two I was pretty surprised. I was expecting `plain` to be the fastest because I'm returning an element from the array and for the opposite reason `arr` to be the slowest because it returns the whole array.

Given the outcome of the experiment I have 2 questions.

- Why is `arr` almost 2 times faster than `plain`?
- Are there any other methods I have missed that can outperform `arr`?

Comment: Your expections are wrong, why **wouldn't** it be faster to just return the array, then to actually iterate over the entire array to find a certain value by key? Even when you use brackets and supply the key, iteration has to happen iternally to find that key.

Comment: @adeneo in the case of `plain` it is not iterating the array, furthermore when I call `arr` and then provide keys to the element I want to get to, I'm actually doing the same thing as `plain` does internally, so how come the results, is what I'm wondering.

Comment: All you need to do to return an array is to return a _reference_. If you're returning a single element, you could be returning a reference also, _but_ it has to do a indirect lookup into the array _before_ returning

Comment: @php_nub_qq Can't reproduce the same results as you got! The `loop` is pretty much the same with my results, but `plain` and `arr` are both +/- at `0.014` for me. What system do you have ? php version?

Comment: @Rizier123 You can check it out [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba9d33c30da00624535d1eb32e2fb1c14e0b9b91), just don't forget to switch to 5.6. Results are not quite as dramatic as on my machine but `arr` is still faster than `plain` every time.

Comment: @php_nub_qq As I said even in the sandbox sometimes even `arr` is slower that `plain` so they are pretty much the same

Comment: @Rizier123 try putting in `1000000` loops, `arr` is always ~20% faster. I know this may be a "maximalist" or "perfectionist" concern but if you operate on a large scale it would matter. Just suppose this is a theoretical rather than practical question.

Comment: @php_nub_qq With 100'000 iterations it's even more closer together, both are on 0.03 - 0.04 so they are both the same for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I said this in the comment, but I decided it's pretty close to an answer.  Your question basically boils down to why is `2+2;` not faster than just plain `2;`

Arrays are just objects stored in memory.  To return an object from a function, you return a memory address (32 or 64 bit unsigned integer), which implies nothing more than pushing a single integer onto the stack.

In the case of returning an index of an array, that index really just represents an *offset* from the base address of the array, so everytime you see a square bracket-style array access, internally PHP (rather the internal C implementation of PHP) is converting the 'index' in the array into an integer that it adds to the memory address of the array to get the memory address of the stored value at that index.

So when you see this kind of code:

```
return $data[$file][$setting][$key][$sub];
```

That says:

> Find me the address of `$data`. Then calculate the offset that the string stored in `$file` is (which involves looking up what `$file` is in memory).  Then do the same for `$setting`, `$key`, and `$sub`.  Finally, add all of those offsets together to get the address (in the case of objects) or the value (in the case of native data types) to push on to the stack as a return value.

It should be no surprise then that returning a simple array is quicker.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. If I switch the values in the test function calling `arr` to variables instead of literals, it becomes slower as expected. In the end my expectations weren't completely wrong, I guess :D

Comment: [link in case you want to check it out](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/03438c97479108525f88b5ede423f9a92636043e)

Answer (score 1):

That's the way `PHP` works. You expect, that a copy of `$data` is returned here. It is not.

What you acutaly have, is a pointer (Something like an ID to a specific place in the memory), which reference the data.

What you return, is the reference to the data, not the data them self.

In the `plain` method, you search for the value first. This cost time. Take a look at [this great article](https://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html), which show, how arrays are working internal.

---

Sometimes Code say's more then words. What you assume is:

```
function arr(){
    global $data;
    //create a copy
    $newData = $data;
    //return reference to $newData
    return $newData;
}
```

Also you should not use `global`, that is bad practise. You can give your array as a parameter.

```
//give a copy of the data, slow
function arr($data) {
    return $data;
}

//give the reference, fast
function arr(&$data) {
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a valid answer, I suppose the only reason for a down vote would be if it is untrue. I will definitely be reading the article later on tonight!